# Insert character in variable using Regular expressions substitutions

Tags: powershell

Sorry in advance if my english is bad,

What I'm trying to do is convert AOS 6 commands to AOS 7 command from a conf file.

To convert the line 'interfaces 2/6 alias "TOTO"' in 'interfaces 2/1/6 alias "TOTO"' i used the following command :

```
'interfaces 2/6 alias "TOTO"' -replace '^interfaces (?<slot>[0-9]/[0-9]{1,2}) alias "(?<alias>[_a-zA-Z0-9]+)"$','interfaces port ${slot} alias "${alias}"'
```

It works fine but what I'm trying to do is insert "1/" in the middle of $slot to give $slot = 2/1/6.
I tryed to do something like this :

```
'interfaces 1/6 alias "TOTO"' -replace '^interfaces (?<slot>[0-9]/[0-9]{1,2}) alias "(?<alias>[_a-zA-Z0-9]+)"$','interfaces port $($slot.insert(2,"1/")) alias "$alias"'
```

But it didn't work.
Does anyone have a solution to modify $slot right after -replace ?
I'm looking for something like

```
'interfaces port $($slot.insert(2,"1/")) alias "$alias"'
```

Here is my code :

```
param($confAOS6Path=$null)

if($confAOS6Path -eq $null){
    $confAOS6Path = Read-Host "Entrer le chemin du fichier AOS verion 6"
}

$confAOS6 = Get-Content $confAOS6Path
$matchList = [PSCustomObject]@{
    '^interfaces (?<slot>[0-9]/[0-9]{1,2}) alias "(?<alias>[_a-zA-Z0-9]+)"$' = 'interfaces port $($slot.insert(2,"1/")) alias "$alias"'
}

foreach($line in $confAOS6){
    foreach($regex in $matchList.PSObject.Properties.Name){
        if($line -match $regex){
            Invoke-Expression '$line -replace $regex,$matchList.$regex'
        }
        else{
            Add-Content -path "test.txt" -Value $line
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
'interfaces 2/6 alias "TOTO"' -replace 
    '^interfaces (?<slot1>[0-9])/(?<slot2>[0-9]{1,2}) alias "(?<alias>[_a-zA-Z0-9]+)"$',
    'interfaces port ${slot1}/1/${slot2} alias "${alias}"'
```